# Dialglfow V2 Authentification

Tags: php, dialogflow-es

since the update of dialogflow (V2), the authentication system changed.
Documentation explain that we have to use this command 'gcloud auth print-access-token' to generate a token.
It works, but after a one hour, the token expire.
I don't understand how to generate the token in PHP without use the Gcloud command.

the Dialogflow documentation about authentification is very light. Does someone understood how to uses this authentification system ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Tokens normally expire and there is normally a response code that say you have to make a call to regenerate the token. So there should also be a call documented to ask for a new token

Comment: Yes, but the V2 dialogflow API use Google Cloud Platform Service Account for authentification. But I don't find documentation to generate or regenerate token in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Create a JSON Web Signature (JWS) to retrieve access_token

Docs: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount